# JDBC Realm configuration in tomcat

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat, jdbc, jdbcrealm

I am trying to configure tomcat to authenticate using SQL Server. I have modified `server.xml` with following:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
         available for use by the Realm.  -->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/> 

    <!--This is only applicable for Tomcat 8.5 and higher version with SQL server authentication-->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
          driverName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    connectionURL="jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:1433;databaseName=xxxx" connectionName="user" connectionPassword="password"  userTable="xx" userNameCol="username" userCredCol="password"/>
</Realm>
```

However I get the following error everytime I try to authenticate:

> SEVERE: Exception performing authentication
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'null'.
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1535)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:467)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:409)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:219)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:199)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:331)
>       at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.getRoles(JDBCRealm.java:601)
>       at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:404)
>       at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:326)
>       at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate(CombinedRealm.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate(LockOutRealm.java:158)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:84)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.authenticate(AuthenticatorBase.java:700)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:599)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Sep 21, 2017 12:00:59 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm getRoles
>   SEVERE: Exception performing authentication
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'null'.
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1535)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:467)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:409)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:219)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:199)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:331)
>       at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.getRoles(JDBCRealm.java:601)
>       at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:404)
>       at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:326)
>       at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate(CombinedRealm.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate(LockOutRealm.java:158)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:84)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.authenticate(AuthenticatorBase.java:700)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:599)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I have put in the `mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar` in the `lib` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your problem is that you don't have specified table with roles assigned to the user. According [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/realm-howto.html#JDBCRealm) regarding JDBC realm:

> - There must be a table, referenced below as the user roles table, that contains one row for every valid role that is assigned to a particular user. It is legal for a user to have zero, one, or more than one valid role.
> - The user roles table must contain at least two columns (it may contain more if your existing applications required it):
>
>   - Username to be recognized by Tomcat (same value as is specified in the users table).
>   - Role name of a valid role associated with this user

Exception stack is also confirms such guess

```
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.getRoles(JDBCRealm.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:404)
```

So, to overcome such problem you should specify roles table `userRoleTable` and role name column `roleNameCol` like this:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
       driverName="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"
       connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/authority?user=dbuser&amp;
       password=dbpass"
       userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass"
       userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name"/>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Sergey, After specifying the role table details, it logs into the application but I get the following error: `HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied` although it it works fine with mysql having same user and role credentials

Comment: @HBK, I have no idea about security your using in your application (and even about application itself), so most likely the problem is that you have some security constraints applied on your resource and such user doesn't have allowed role.